# Bind ListView from remote datasource using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile. I need to populate the ListView from db. I was checking this forum link:

http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2012/06/10/html5-custom-listviews-with-jquerymobile/

I would like to do the same, but I want to get all the data from database (image and corresponding data). I was able to populate Listview from remote datasource. But that was simple, not having any image. The following is that code. But I am not sure how I can apply that approach here and have more custom look to listview and data binding from remote data source.

```
<div data-role="content">
   <ul data-role="listview" id="contentListView" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"></ul>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       $(function(){
           var serviceUrl='http://mydatasource:81/Service.asmx/show';
               $.ajax({
                   url:serviceUrl,
                   success:function(xml){
                       setTimeout(function(){
                           feedItem = '';
                           $(xml).find( "newset" ).each(function(){
                               var item = $(this),
                               title =  item.find('EmployeeID').text(),
                               link =  item.find('FirstName').text()
                               feedItem = feedItem + '<li class="test"><a class="test2" href="#">';
                               feedItem = feedItem + link;
                               feedItem = feedItem + '</a></li>';
                           });
                           $('#contentListView').append(feedItem);
                       },100);
                   },
                   error:function(){
               },
               dataType:"xml"
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Thanks.
Bavya.

---

Thanks a lot for your reply..really appreciated.. but when I try your same code its redirecting me to the 'Network error has occurred!' alert. Am I missing something. BTW i tried this in visual studio. Here is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        li span
        {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>
                XML Parsing demo</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="cars-data">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="cars">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="a" href="#index">Back</a>
            <h1>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="car-data">
            </ul>
            <img src="" width="100%" style="height: auto;" id="car-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
            $('#cars-data').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/echo/xml/",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: {
                    xml: "<cars><car><name>TOYOTA</name><country>JAPAN</country><pic>http://1call.ms/Websites/schwartz2012/images/toyota-rav4.jpg</pic><description>Toyota has announced that it will recall a total of 778,000 units that may have been manufactured with improperly-tightened nuts on the rear suspension.</description></car></cars>"
                },
                success: function (xml) {
                    ajax.parseXML(xml);
                },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    alert('Network error has occurred!');
                }
            });
        });

        $("#cars").live('pagebeforeshow', function () {
            $("#cars div[data-role='header'] h1").html(carObject.carName);
            $('#car-data').empty();
            $('#car-data').append('<li>Car Type:<span> ' + carObject.carName + '</span></li>');
            $('#car-data').append('<li>Car Country:<span> ' + carObject.carCountry + '</span></li>');
            $('#car-data').append('<li>Car Description:<span> ' + carObject.description + '</span></li>');
            $('#car-data').listview('refresh');
            $('#car-img').attr('src', carObject.img)
        });

        var ajax = {
            parseXML: function (result) {
                $(result).find("car").each(function () {
                    carObject.carName = $(this).find('name').text();
                    carObject.carCountry = $(this).find('country').text();
                    carObject.img = $(this).find('pic').text();
                    carObject.description = $(this).find('description').text();

                    $('#cars-data').append('<li><a href="#cars"><img src="' + carObject.img + '" title="sample" height="100%" width="100%"/><h3>Car type:<span> ' + carObject.carName + '</span></h3><p>' + carObject.description + '</p></a></li>');
                });
                $('#cars-data').listview('refresh');
            }
        }

        var carObject = {
            carName: '',
            carCountry: '',
            img: '',
            description: ''
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my example, I made it for someone else but it can still be used in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/

My datasource is a xml, unfortunately xml can not be acquired from remote domains so jsFiddle has a mockup $.ajax xml fetching, still this example will show you how to do what you want.

To create a custom listview you need this template:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/sample.jpg" title="sample"/>
        <h3>Sample image</h3>
        <p>Sample</p>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/sample.jpg" title="sample"/>
        <h3>Sample image</h3>
        <p>Sample 2</p>
     </a></li>
</ul>
```

My example will show you how to populate this kind of listview (in my case from xml, but method is same with json) and display this data in the new page.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes and its worked for me. Thanks a lot again. I am pasting my code here. Hope it will help someone who is using remote datasource.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        li span
         {
            font-weight: normal;
         }
     </style>
   <title> Sample App using jQuery Mobile</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
   <head>
   <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="car">
         <div data-role="header" data-postion="fixed">
            <h1> Cars</h1>
            <h1 id="blogheader">Loading...</h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="contentListView">
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
             <h1> Footer </h1>
         </div>
     </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
       var serviceUrl='http://mysite:81/Service.asmx/ShowListViewData';
       $.ajax({
         url:serviceUrl,
         success:function(xml){
         setTimeout(
         function(){
            $(xml).find( "newset" ).each(function(){
                carName  = $(this).find('ItemName').text();
                img  = $(this).find('ImageUrl').text();
                description  = $(this).find('ItemDescription').text();
                $('#contentListView').append('<li><a href="#"><img src="' + img + '" title="sample" height="100%" width="100%"/><h3>Car type:<span> '+carName+'</span></h3><p>' + description + '</p></a></li>');
            });
        $('#contentListView').listview('refresh');
       }
       ,100);
      },
       error:function(){
      },
       dataType:"xml"
   });
 });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my webservice:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Configuration;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod()]
    public void ShowListViewData()
    {
        string connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        string s = "SELECT ImageUrl,ItemName,ItemDescription FROM ListViewSource";
        SqlCommand.CommandText = s;
        SqlCommand.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "newset");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ds.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks.